# Web Scraping NBA Reference for Misc Stats

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm new to web scraping and trying to retrieve the miscellaneous table from https://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2021.html using Beautifulsoup. I have some code written but I'm unable to print the required table and just returns none.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from urllib.request import urlopen
import pandas as pd 

url = "http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2021.html"
data = urlopen(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(data)

table = soup.find('table', id='misc_stats')
print(table)
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The sports-reference.com sites have some of those tables within the comments of the source html. So you need to pull out the comments, then parse the tables in there:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, Comment
import pandas as pd

headers = {'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.104 Safari/537.36'}

url = "http://www.basketball-reference.com/leagues/NBA_2021.html"
response = requests.get(url, headers=headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(response.content, 'html.parser')
comments = soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))

tables = []
for each in comments:
    if 'table' in str(each):
        try:
            tables.append(pd.read_html(each, attrs = {'id': 'misc_stats'}, header=1)[0])
        except:
            continue

df = tables[0]
```

**Output:**

```
print(df.to_string())
      Rk                    Team   Age     W     L  PW  PL   MOV   SOS   SRS   ORtg   DRtg  NRtg   Pace    FTr   3PAr    TS%   eFG%  TOV%  ORB%  FT/FGA  eFG%.1  TOV%.1  DRB%  FT/FGA.1                       Arena  Attend.  Attend./G
0    1.0      Los Angeles Lakers  29.0  16.0   6.0  16   6  7.73 -0.08  7.65  112.6  104.8   7.8   99.3  0.257  0.352  0.578  0.547  13.1  23.3   0.193   0.513    12.9  80.5     0.152              STAPLES Center        0          0
1    2.0               Utah Jazz  28.5  16.0   5.0  15   6  7.57 -0.20  7.38  115.9  108.2   7.7   98.2  0.245  0.485  0.587  0.557  13.1  26.2   0.185   0.507    10.4  79.7     0.152     Vivint Smart Home Arena    21290       1935
2    3.0         Milwaukee Bucks  28.0  12.0   8.0  15   5  8.15 -0.79  7.36  118.4  110.4   8.0  101.8  0.225  0.425  0.598  0.576  12.5  24.7   0.164   0.532    11.7  79.7     0.161                Fiserv Forum        0          0
3    4.0    Los Angeles Clippers  29.1  16.0   6.0  16   6  7.23 -1.13  6.10  117.8  110.4   7.4   97.4  0.235  0.413  0.603  0.565  12.1  22.2   0.200   0.537    13.3  80.0     0.189              STAPLES Center        0          0
4    5.0          Denver Nuggets  26.5  12.0   8.0  13   7  4.95 -0.19  4.76  117.0  112.0   5.0   97.1  0.244  0.383  0.587  0.556  12.5  26.1   0.187   0.551    13.8  78.7     0.204                  Ball Arena        0          0
5    6.0           Brooklyn Nets  28.1  14.0   9.0  14   9  4.48 -0.56  3.92  117.9  113.5   4.4  101.9  0.264  0.415  0.620  0.584  13.4  20.5   0.217   0.524    10.6  77.6     0.192             Barclays Center        0          0
6    7.0            Phoenix Suns  26.6  11.0   8.0  11   8  2.84  0.24  3.08  110.8  108.0   2.8   97.5  0.214  0.428  0.572  0.537  12.3  18.9   0.179   0.521    12.4  80.0     0.193          Phoenix Suns Arena        0          0
7    8.0      Philadelphia 76ers  26.7  15.0   6.0  13   8  4.19 -1.13  3.06  111.5  107.4   4.1  101.6  0.299  0.351  0.576  0.538  13.8  23.7   0.228   0.515    13.4  77.9     0.199          Wells Fargo Center        0          0
8    9.0           Atlanta Hawks  24.3  10.0  10.0  12   8  2.50  0.26  2.76  112.2  109.7   2.5   99.2  0.298  0.396  0.564  0.517  12.9  25.1   0.243   0.506    11.5  77.1     0.203            State Farm Arena     3529        353
9   10.0          Boston Celtics  25.5  11.0   8.0  11   8  2.53 -0.03  2.50  112.4  109.8   2.6   99.3  0.236  0.359  0.570  0.541  13.4  25.3   0.178   0.536    13.8  77.9     0.209                   TD Garden        0          0
10  11.0       Memphis Grizzlies  24.8   9.0   7.0   9   7  1.31  1.15  2.47  108.9  107.6   1.3  100.6  0.192  0.327  0.551  0.523  12.4  23.0   0.149   0.530    14.6  77.5     0.190                 FedEx Forum      410         51
11  12.0          Indiana Pacers  26.8  12.0   9.0  12   9  2.71 -0.33  2.38  113.0  110.3   2.7   99.9  0.238  0.381  0.583  0.553  12.6  20.4   0.182   0.533    13.3  76.9     0.194     Bankers Life Fieldhouse        0          0
12  13.0         Houston Rockets  28.4  10.0   9.0  11   8  2.95 -0.97  1.98  109.4  106.5   2.9  102.1  0.255  0.445  0.573  0.541  13.7  19.3   0.193   0.512    13.5  76.8     0.195               Toyota Center    28141       3127
13  14.0         Toronto Raptors  27.2   9.0  12.0  12   9  1.67 -1.33  0.34  111.6  109.9   1.7  100.2  0.238  0.479  0.570  0.532  12.9  22.0   0.195   0.533    14.9  77.4     0.234                Amalie Arena    10989        999
14  15.0        Dallas Mavericks  26.4   8.0  13.0   9  12 -2.00  2.00  0.00  109.6  111.6  -2.0   98.7  0.264  0.411  0.559  0.525  11.3  18.5   0.199   0.530    12.7  76.7     0.216    American Airlines Center        0          0
15  16.0       San Antonio Spurs  26.9  11.0  10.0  10  11 -1.05  0.92 -0.13  110.3  111.3  -1.0  100.3  0.224  0.331  0.550  0.516  10.0  19.9   0.175   0.547    12.5  78.8     0.156                 AT&T Center        0          0
16  17.0   Golden State Warriors  26.7  11.0  10.0  10  11 -1.05  0.77 -0.28  108.6  109.6  -1.0  103.2  0.262  0.417  0.563  0.527  12.7  18.4   0.201   0.514    13.5  75.8     0.249                Chase Center        0          0
17  18.0       Charlotte Hornets  24.8  10.0  11.0  10  11 -0.62 -0.41 -1.03  110.2  110.8  -0.6   99.0  0.247  0.414  0.560  0.529  13.1  23.3   0.185   0.544    14.1  75.0     0.166             Spectrum Center        0          0
18  19.0         New York Knicks  24.4   9.0  13.0  10  12 -2.00  0.53 -1.47  107.1  109.2  -2.1   95.4  0.264  0.319  0.538  0.500  12.6  23.8   0.203   0.503    10.7  76.9     0.198  Madison Square Garden (IV)        0          0
19  20.0  Portland Trail Blazers  27.3  11.0   9.0   9  11 -1.65 -0.07 -1.72  115.0  116.6  -1.6   99.8  0.229  0.460  0.567  0.529  10.1  21.5   0.190   0.560    12.2  78.0     0.209                 Moda Center        0          0
20  21.0           Chicago Bulls  24.9   8.0  11.0   8  11 -2.26  0.36 -1.90  110.9  113.1  -2.2  103.4  0.246  0.413  0.590  0.556  15.2  20.8   0.196   0.553    12.9  80.0     0.217               United Center        0          0
21  22.0    New Orleans Pelicans  25.1   7.0  12.0   8  11 -2.58 -0.17 -2.75  110.3  112.8  -2.5   99.6  0.284  0.365  0.558  0.526  13.4  25.6   0.203   0.549    12.8  79.9     0.193        Smoothie King Center     8820        980
22  23.0         Detroit Pistons  26.3   5.0  16.0   7  14 -4.67  1.82 -2.85  107.7  112.4  -4.7   98.5  0.273  0.408  0.544  0.501  13.0  22.6   0.215   0.558    14.2  76.6     0.194        Little Caesars Arena        0          0
23  24.0     Cleveland Cavaliers  24.7  10.0  11.0   8  13 -4.19  0.04 -4.15  104.9  109.1  -4.2   97.2  0.254  0.309  0.536  0.505  14.4  25.9   0.181   0.537    14.9  75.3     0.170         Quicken Loans Arena    12564       1142
24  25.0              Miami Heat  26.7   7.0  13.0   7  13 -5.45  0.29 -5.16  106.9  112.3  -5.4   98.9  0.263  0.452  0.581  0.547  15.7  17.0   0.204   0.543    13.3  76.6     0.183      AmericanAirlines Arena        0          0
25  26.0        Sacramento Kings  25.7   9.0  11.0   7  13 -5.80  0.45 -5.35  112.7  118.4  -5.7  100.1  0.283  0.377  0.576  0.546  13.0  23.5   0.203   0.558    11.6  75.8     0.194             Golden 1 Center        0          0
26  27.0      Washington Wizards  26.2   4.0  13.0   6  11 -5.29 -0.85 -6.14  112.1  117.2  -5.1  104.4  0.282  0.374  0.569  0.534  11.6  20.7   0.212   0.565    12.8  78.9     0.251           Capital One Arena        0          0
27  28.0   Oklahoma City Thunder  23.7   8.0  11.0   5  14 -8.26  0.61 -7.66  105.2  113.3  -8.1  101.3  0.243  0.446  0.556  0.527  12.9  15.7   0.176   0.537    10.9  77.7     0.157     Chesapeake Energy Arena        0          0
28  29.0           Orlando Magic  26.2   8.0  14.0   6  16 -6.82 -1.40 -8.22  105.5  112.3  -6.8   98.9  0.220  0.358  0.526  0.490  12.2  24.1   0.174   0.547    12.4  79.7     0.173                Amway Center    35768       3252
29  30.0  Minnesota Timberwolves  23.5   5.0  15.0   5  15 -9.30  0.55 -8.76  104.6  113.7  -9.1  101.1  0.230  0.377  0.530  0.497  12.7  23.3   0.174   0.539    13.3  75.0     0.217               Target Center        0          0
30   NaN          League Average  26.3   NaN   NaN  10  10  0.00  0.00  0.00  111.1  111.1   NaN   99.8  0.250  0.396  0.568  0.534  12.8  22.2   0.193   0.534    12.8  77.8     0.193                         NaN     4050        400
```

If you look at the source html, you'll see the tables in the comments start with `<!--`

BeautifulSoup skips over those. Hense, you need to add the part in the code that specifically finds the comments `comments = soup.find_all(string=lambda text: isinstance(text, Comment))`. Once you have all the comments, then you can iterate through each comment to see if theres a table in there. If there's a table, parse it, like you normally would with the non commented `<table>` tags.

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm still new to this so can you show me where I can find the tables within the comments of the source html?

Comment: @abso-shen123 I added a little explanation. see if that makes sense